# Calling PHP File from Node.js with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ajax, socket.io

## The Problem:

Hello, I currently have a website with a game on it that is running with node.js. It includes gulp and socket.io.

I have a php file that I want to call from node.js, and it returns the success message (echo in file), but does not update my database.

However, when I call the php file by putting the link in the browser or calling it with the same AJAX command from my website, it works perfectly fine.

So from my website: site.com, the php file works perfectly, but from my node server: site.com:3000, it returns success but does not update my DB.

I know that Node is not compatible with php but maybe there is a workaround around this.

I also noticed that my variables are empty when calling the file from node.

---

## Code:

Here is my php file:

**subtract5.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://cashballz.net:3000', false);
include 'mysql.php'; 
session_start(); 

$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$_SESSION['cash_amount'] -= 0.05;

$mysql = new Mysql(); 

$result = $mysql->setCashAmount($cash_amount,$userid); 
if($result) 
{ 
echo "5 cents have been subtracted!"; 
} 
else 
{ 
session_start(); 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
}
?>
```

**mysql.php**

```
<?php
class Mysql 
{ 
protected $dsn; 
protected $username; 
protected $password; 
public $db; 


function __construct() 
{ 
//change this to your info (myDBname, myName, myPass) 
$this->dns= 'mysql:dbname=cashball_accounts;host=localhost;charset=utf8'; 
$this->username= 'cashball_root'; 
$this->password= '1VeryBright*'; 
$this->db = new PDO($this->dns, $this->username, $this->password); 
} 


public function setCashAmount($cash_amount, $id) 
{ 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = :cash_amount - 0.05 WHERE id = :id"; 
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':cash_amount', $cash_amount, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
return $result; 
} 

} 
?>
```

**And my AJAX call: (app.js)**

```
//cut 5 cents from account - php function
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php',
    data: {}, 
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

---

## Conclusion:

I need a way to properly run my php script and update my database directly from node.js. I have seen solutions to this with files on github, but i don't understand if this is the right solution or how to implement them in my code. Maybe there is a way to call the php file through a different domain in the background with ajax?

I am a beginner to PHP and decent at JS, so please add detail your answers.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should separate each entity into it's own class, not a generic Mysql class for everything. But that aside .. have you var_dumped throughout your function to see what's actually happening?

Comment: Yes so the $_SESSION variables are empty when called from node.js.

Answer (score 0):

so what I'm wondering

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

what will the sql statement be when called from Node? Can you debug that (when it's called from Node)

My guess would be that

```
$_SESSION
```

is empty when called from Node

Comment: Yes all the $_SESSION variables are not defined when the file is called from node.

Comment: Where can i check the sql statement? I'm a beginner to PHP so i am slightly confused.

Comment: don't know .. you're using some sort of database abstraction layer class.

Answer (score 0):

As you state in some comment the `$_SESSION` variables are empty. Assuming that you have the same data (id and cash amount) available in your node.js you could pass it along with the AJAX call, something like this:

```
//cut 5 cents from account - php function
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php',
    data: {
        'id' : 'someid_probablyasint',
        'cash_amount' : 'someamount_probablyasint'
    }, 
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

You can then access the variables that you passed along via `$_POST` in your php file -- because of `type: "POST"`. Something along these lines:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://cashballz.net:3000', false);
include 'mysql.php';

$cash_amount = $_POST['cash_amount'];
$userid = $_POST['id'];
$new_cash_amount = $cash_amount - 0.05;

$mysql = new Mysql();

$result = $mysql->setCashAmount($cash_amount, $userid);
if ($result) {
    echo json_encode([
        'new_cash_amount' => $new_cash_amount,
        'message' => '5 cents have been subtracted!'
    ]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Huge error.']);
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to securely pass the variables from my website to the node.js game.

Comment: And i need a way to pass the session variables because i also affect them in the php code, so this solution wouldn't work for me. I need a way to call the php file as if i'm just putting the link in the background.

Comment: Maybe i could iframe the php file and just display:hidden? I really don't know

Comment: If i could figure out how to make it work with AJAX that would be better because if i need to pass data to the file it is possible.

Comment: If you need to pass it to your `node.js` game, you could make another AJAX request to fetch this data, assuming you have the `user_id` in the game. Or alternatively you could only pass the `user_id` from your game and run the query based on that info.